# Connecting python to web server

Tags: python

I was trying to write variables on an html file, 
using the commands

```
index = open('/var/www/index.html','a')
index.write('...')
index.close()
```

The problems that I am facing are:

1. how to clear previous values from html file using python commands
2. how to move to next line on html using python ( '\n' is not working).

Comment: Windows uses `\r\n` for newlines. HTML ignores newlines. To have it show text on the next line, in your browser, use `<br>`.

Comment: You may also need to check file permissions.

Comment: I don't understand 1. Do you mean just overwriting the file? Then use `'w'` instead of `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

As L3viathan mentioned, 'w' is used for over-writing the file.
When you use 'a', you're appending to the existing file.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files